# Parametric function with maximum problem

Tags: real-analysis

We consider the function $f(x, y) = (x + y)(e^{x - y} - 1) + kxy$. Is there a value for $k$ for which the function has a local maximum? I have found that:
$
f_{xx}(x, y) = e^{x - y}(2 + x + y), \quad f_{yy}(x, y) = e^{x - y}(-2 + x + y), \quad f_{xy}(x, y) = -(x + y)e^{x - y} + k
$
After calculations, I found that the Hessian function $H(x, y)$ is a quadratic form, and I tried to prove that it has a negative discriminant to show that it has a negative sign. However, I got stuck there.

Answer (score 2):

Changing variables to $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$, we have

$$f(x,y)=f(u,v)=u(e^v-1)+ku^2-kv^2$$

where $k/4$ is scaled to $k$ for simplicity. If there is a local maximum, then $\nabla f=0$, that is,

$$\partial_uf=e^v-1+2ku=0\ \ \text{and}\ \ \partial_vf=ue^v-2kv=0.$$

Let $t=1-2ku$, the first equation yields $v=\log(t)$, taking into the second yields

$$tu^2=(1-t)\log(t).$$

Since $t>0$ and $(1-t)\log(t)\leq0$, the above equation has only one solution $(u,t)=(0,1)$, which gives $(u,v)=(0,0)$. This means for all $k\in\mathbb R$ the only possible local maximum is at the origin, but we can easily show it is a saddle point by using the second derivatives $f_{uu}=2k$, $f_{uv}=e^v$ and $f_{vv}=ue^v-2k$.